# What does this Apple Watch OS Warning: "No custom interface defined for category "(null)". Will use system default presentation" mean?

Tags: ios, watchkit

When I receive a PUSH notification on the watch and tap it, the console prints this message:

```
"no custom interface defined for category "(null)". Will use system default presentation."
```

Not a lot of documentation exists alluding to the actual crux of the issue, what does it mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your notification payload doesn't include a `category` key and you don't have an interface that uses the default.

You can either include `"category": "myCategory"` in your payload, where the value matches the Notification Category set in your storyboard or you can set the Notification Category to `default`.

To set or change the category:

1. Open your Interface storyboard and select the arrow to the left of your static interface.

   [image: Notification Category]
2. Change the Name property in the Attributes Inspector.

   [image: Notification Category]

See the *Configuring the Category of a Custom Interface* section of [Managing a Custom Long Look Interface](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/CustomzingthePushNotificationInterface.html) for more information.